# How can I fix my .html file association in Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, mime-types

PCManFM 1.2.0 and Caja 1.8.1.

When I double-click an HTML document in Caja or PCManFM, it tries to open the document in Thunderbird.  In Start -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications, Firefox is listed as the default web browser, Thunderbird as the mail client.

How can I open HTML documents in Firefox by default?

Comment: Also, I could've sworn I already solved this once, a few weeks ago.  What causes this breakage to keep occurring?

Comment: Sorry, that was a brain fart.  I obviously want to open them in a web browser.  Opening them in Thunderbird doesn't even display anything (despite it supporting HTML e-mail.)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click an HTML file, go Open With->Open With, check "make this the default" and choose Firefox.

Why I needed to do this again, having just done it a few weeks ago, maybe I should post as a second question.